# How to populate binary matrices with all the combinations?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, binary

I want to have 2^n matrices with all the combinations of 0 and 1 in them. For example, for n=6 (n=#rows x #columns) `array{1}=[0 0 0; 0 0 0]`,`array{2}=[0 0 0; 0 0 1]`... `array{64}=[1 1 1;1 1 1]`. I am using MATLAB and I came across with  `combn.m`  (M = COMBN(V,N) returns all combinations of N elements of the elements in vector V. M has the size (length(V).^N)-by-N.), `dec2bin()` but I can't get it quite right. Another idea of mine was to create a large matrix and then split it into 2^n matrices. For instance,for n=6( 2 x 3), i did this `M=combn([0 1],3)` which gives me:

```
M =

 0     0     0
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
 0     1     1
 1     0     0
 1     0     1
 1     1     0
 1     1     1
```

Then, use this `M` to create a larger matrix like this `M2=combn(M,2)`, but this produces the wrong results. However, if i concatenate M row like this:

`M=combn([000;010;100;001;110;011;101;111],2)'` I get something closer to what I expect i.e

```
M =

Columns 1 through 21

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10   100   100   100   100   100
 0    10   100     1   110    11   101   111     0    10   100     1   110    11   101   111     0    10   100     1   110

 Columns 22 through 42

   100   100   100     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1   110   110   110   110   110   110   110   110    11    11
11   101   111     0    10   100     1   110    11   101   111     0    10   100     1   110    11   101   111     0    10

  Columns 43 through 63

  11    11    11    11    11    11   101   101   101   101   101   101   101   101   111   111   111   111   111   111   111
  100     1   110    11   101   111     0    10   100     1   110    11   101   111     0    10   100     1   110    11   101

  Column 64

   111
   111
```

where I can get each column and convert it separately into 64 matrices.So, for example column 1 would be converted from `[0;0]` to `[0 0 0;0 0 0]` etc. However, i believe it is a much easier problem which it can be solved in less time, elegantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html):

```
r = 2; %// nunber of rows
c = 3; %// number of columns

M = dec2bin(0:2^(r*c)-1)-'0'; %// Or: M = de2bi(0:2^(r*c)-1);
M = reshape(M.',r,c,[]);
```

`M` is a 3D-array of size `r` x `c` x `2^(r*c)`, such that `M(:,:,1)` is the first matrix, `M(:,:,2)` is the second etc.

*How it works*:

`dec2bin` gives a binary string representation of a number. So `dec2bin(0:2^(r*c)-1)` gives all numbers from `0` to `2^(r*c)-1` expressed in binary, each in one row. The `-'0'` part just turns the string into a numeric vector of `0` and `1` values. Then `reshape` puts each of those rows into a `r` x `c` form, to make up each of the the desired matrices.

Comment: how do you control n? i mean n could be 6 but 2 rows by 3 columns. Can you relate it to the example above?

Comment: @JustCurious Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully. I have now, and I don't understand what you want

Comment: i want 2^n binary matrices. each matrix should be different from the other but have the same #rows x #columns. Importantly, n=#rows x #columns. So for n=6,i want to have 64 matrices each one have a different combination of zeros and ones. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very elegant! Exactly what I wanted! Would you mind explaining how dec2bin and reshape worked in this occasion?

Comment: @JustCurious Thanks! I've added an explantion in my answer