# Matlab: How to generate the set of 3x3 matrices containing all combinations and permutations of ones and/or zeroes (with one constraint)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'd like to generate the set of 3x3 matrices containing all permutations and combinations of ones and/or zeroes (ie. including zeros matrix and ones matrix), but with one constraint: If any row (say 'a') contains more than one 1 entry, any other row (say 'b') with a 1 entry in one of these columns must also contain a 1 entry in the other column(s) in which row 'a' holds a 1 entry.

I hope that's clear and would be very grateful for any help,

Thanks,

Harry

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it, but are you looking for all 3x3 binary matrices with a column sum of at most 1?

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I didn't understand the constrain you're imposing. Could you add examples?

Comment: i'd just create a vector of length 9 of all permutation using dec2bin and reshape it to 3x3xN

Comment: this was recently demonstrated, see here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116510/how-to-populate-binary-matrices-with-all-the-combinations/23116596#23116596

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is intended to just iterate over all such matrices and `doStuff` with them. If you want to allocate all possibilities in memory, this may not be the most efficient way of doing it.

This approach is based on the fact that the binary representation of in a given range (here from 0 to 2^9) will enumerate all possible combinations of 0's and 1's in that range.

Checking the constraint follows your description more or less directly and ended up being a bit lenghty  :-)

```
enumerateMatrices(3)

% Function enumerateMatrices:
function result = enumerateMatrices(n)
    result = [];
    for i = 1:2^(n*n)
        array = dec2bin(i-1, n*n) - '0';
        matrix = reshape(array, n, n);
        if ~checkConstraint(matrix, n)
            continue;
        end
        result(:, :, end+1) = matrix; %#ok<AGROW>
        doStuff(matrix);
    end
end

function met = checkConstraint(matrix, n)
    met = true;
    for i=1:n
        countOnes = sum(matrix(i, :));
        if (countOnes <= 1)
            continue;
        end
        samePositions = matrix(:, matrix(i, :) == 1);
        sumSamePositions = sum(samePositions, 2);
        if ~all(sumSamePositions == 0 | sumSamePositions == countOnes)
            met = false;
        end
    end
end

function doStuff(matrix)
    matrix;
end
```

This returns 129 out of 512 possible results, such as these:

```
...
ans(:,:,122) =

     1     0     1
     1     0     1
     0     1     0


ans(:,:,123) =

     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     0     0     0


ans(:,:,124) =

     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     0     0     1


ans(:,:,125) =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     0     0     0

...
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was attempting to get! And apologies to the others for any misuse of the forum, I know for next time.