# How can I create systematic matrices in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, modulo

I'm setting up a script and I want it to systematically go through ALL POSSIBLE 2x2, 3x3, and 4x4 matrices modulo 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7. For example, for modulus 2 in a 2x2, there would be 16 possibilities (4^2 because there are 4 positions with 2 possibilities each). I'm having trouble getting MATLAB to not only form all these possibilities but to put them through my script one at a time. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23116510/2586922) may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses [allcomb](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb) from matlab file exchange.

```
%size
n=2
%maximum value
m=2
%generate input for allcomb
e=cell(1,n^2)
e(1:end)={[0:m-1]}
%generate all combinations.
F=reshape(allcomb(e{:}),[],n,n)
```

F is a 3D-Matrix, to get the first possibility use:

```
squeeze(F(1,:,:))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Just to make sure I understand, if I raise n to 3 or 4, do I need to change e so it reads n^3 or F so it has multiple n values? Sorry if these are obvious; I'm new to MATLAB and there's only so far their help files can get you!

Comment: n^2 is the size of the matrix. A nxn matrix has n^2 elements. Changing to 3 and updating the last line would allow nxnxn matrices.

Answer (score 1):

A slight generalization of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116510/how-to-populate-binary-matrices-with-all-the-combinations) does the job in one line:

```
r = 2; %// number of rows
c = 2; %// number of columns
n = 2; %// considered values: 0, 1, ..., n-1

M = reshape(dec2base(0:n^(r*c)-1, n).' - '0', r,c,[]);
```

Result for `r`, `c`, `n` as above:

```
M(:,:,1) =

     0     0
     0     0

M(:,:,2) =

     0     0
     0     1

...

M(:,:,16) =

     1     1
     1     1
```